# Overriden HandleUnauthorizedAsync not being called .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, unauthorized, custom-authentication

I have implemented my own custom authentication middleware and handler, and configured them in the app startup. This is all working fine.

In my custom auth handler where I have overriden HandleAuthenticateAsync() to do my own custom auth, I have also overriden HandleUnauthorizedAsync() in order to redirect the user to the login page, but this isn't getting called.

The browser is receiving a 401 (Unauthorized) in the response. I was expecting my HandleUnauthorizedAsync() to be called.

Am I not understanding the pipeline correctly here?

Thanks

Comment: I managed to get it to fire HandleUnauthorizedAsync() by setting AutomaticChallenge = true in my auth options.

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on this? By default custom auth middleware doesn't have AutomaticChallenge. How did you incorporate that? Am I missing an interface inheritance other than AuthenticationSchemeOptions?

Answer (score 16):

user1859022's helped in my case, but I didn't want to type a name of my scheme for every `[Authorize]`. And specifying `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` didn't work at first as well.

My mistake was kinda stupid. I had both `app.UseAuthorization()` and `app.UseAuthentication()` and of course the order was wrong. The correct version is

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}
```

So make sure that `UseAuthentication` is called **before** `UseAuthorization`.

In .NET7 they have simplified it so there lines of code can be used:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I just needed to stop in here and say "bless you".  I have been beating my head against ILSpy for the past day trying to understand the AuthorizationMiddleware.  My custom token validator would go off, successfully validate the token, but then I would always dump into the Challenge event and the api call would come back with 401.   I now know, that will be the behavior if you went with the project template defaults without thinking to go in and add 

    app.UseAuthentication();

in the proper place. :)

Comment: ORDERING IS IMPORTANT So make sure that UseAuthentication is called before UseAuthorization.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, but this also solved my problem :D

Answer (score 12):

in my case the reason for my handler not being called was that my `AuthenticationScheme` wasn't selected as default. 
I had to include it in my `Authorize` attribute like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes= "MyAuth")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    ...
}
```

btw: the `AutomaticChallenge` option seems to have been removed in `.net core 2.0`

Comment: Is there another way to do it, like not in the controller section?

Answer (score 4):

The above solution did work for me as well I was able to improve on it with following code segment, then there is no need to specify the authentication scheme name in the `[Authorize]` attribute. It is important to call the `AddAuthentication` method before `AddMvc`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //must be placed before the AddMvc call
    services.AddAuthentication(options => 
                {                    
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "MyAuth";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyAuth";
                })
                .AddCustomAuth(o => { });
    
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: Similarly, app.UseAuthenication() must be called before app.UseMvc()

Answer (score 3):

Mihail's answer solved it for me, but just so that it's clear:

If your request is hitting `ChallengeAsync` but not `HandleAuthenticateAsync` or `AuthenticateAsync`

Then check your ordering:

1. `app.UseAuthentication();`
2. `app.UseAuthorization();`